# ReactJS / window.open, забрать данные из дочерней страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

По кнопке происходит запрос, который возвращает данные в открытую, по window.open, страницу.
Как в reactjs получить доступ к этой информации? Страницы находятся в одном домене.
Простым присваиванием

```
const newWindow =  window.open(url);
```

получаю доступ к дом дереву, но еще без нужных данных. Возможно нужно как-то обновить дом дерево, чтобы получить нужные данные?

Answer (score 0):

Решение можно найти тут
https://learn.javascript.ru/popup-windows

Данные получаются через событие onload.